# Comparison by category in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe roughly like this:

```
   category  value
1         A      2
2         B      5
3         A      3
4         A      2
5         B      1
```

Now I want to add a column that tells me if the current value is above or below the medium *in its category*, but I can't figure out how. For the total mean I could just `df["above_mean"] = (df["value"] > df["value"].mean())`, but how do I compare the values to the mean values of their respective categories?

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
   category  value  above_mean
1         A      2       False
2         B      50       True
3         A      3        True
4         A      2       False
5         B      10       True
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you need:

```
print (df.groupby('category')['value'].mean())
category
A    2.333333
B    3.000000
Name: value, dtype: float64

df['above_mean'] = df.groupby('category')['value'].apply(lambda x: x > x.mean())
print (df)
  category  value above_mean
1        A      2      False
2        B      5       True
3        A      3       True
4        A      2      False
5        B      1      False
```

Alternative solution with [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) and compare with [`gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.gt.html) (`>`):

```
print (df.groupby('category')['value'].transform('mean'))
1    2.333333
2    3.000000
3    2.333333
4    2.333333
5    3.000000
Name: value, dtype: float64

df['above_mean'] = df['value'].gt(df.groupby('category')['value'].transform('mean'))
#same as
#df['above_mean'] = df['value'] > df.groupby('category')['value'].transform('mean')
print (df)
  category  value above_mean
1        A      2      False
2        B      5       True
3        A      3       True
4        A      2      False
5        B      1      False
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! That also helped me understand `transform()`, that I had't used before!